# jqwik strategies for combining arbitraries

Tags: java, jqwik

(Context: my background in property-based testing is mostly from scala's scalacheck library, the use of some of the types and annotations in jqwik feels a bit different and there are a couple paradigms I can't quite get the hang of yet.)

I'm not sure how best to combine existing `Arbitrary` definitions for primitive types to produce a re-usable (needed for more than a single `@Property` or test class) Arbitrary that is built atop other `Aribtrary` definitions I've defined.

Given this is probably much clearer with an illustration:

```java
// assume this has a builder pattern or all-args constructor.
// consider this is some sort of core domain object that I need in various 
// test suites
public class MyComplexClass {
  private final String id; // positive-integer shaped
  private final String recordId; // uuid-shaped
  private final String creatorId; // positive-integer shaped
  private final String editorId; // positive-integer shaped
  private final String nonce; // uuid-shaped
  private final String payload; // random string
}
```

My instinct is to define `Aribrary<String>` that produces UUID-like strings and another that produces positive integer strings, something like:

```java
public class MyArbitraries {
  public Arbitrary<String> arbUuidString() {
                return Combinators.combine(
                            Arbitraries.longs(), Arbitraries.longs(), Arbitraries.of(Set.of('8', '9', 'a', 'b')))
                    .as((l1, l2, y) -> {
                        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(new UUID(l1, l2).toString());
                        b.setCharAt(14, '4');
                        b.setCharAt(19, y);
                        return UUID.fromString(b.toString());
                    });
  }

  public Arbitrary<String> arbNumericIdString() {
    return Arbitraries.shorts().map(Math::abs).map(i -> "" + i);
  }
}
```

But then I'm not sure the best way to utilize these to produce an `Arbitrary< MyComplexClass>`. I'd want something like:

```java
public class MyDomain extends DomainContextBase {
  @Provider
  public Arbitrary<MyComplexClass> arbMyComplexClass() {
    return Builders.withBuilder(MyComplexClass::newBuilder)
      // best way to reference these?!
      .use(arbNumericIdString()).in(MyComplexClass.Builder::setId)
      .use(arbUuidString()).in(MyComplexClass.Builder::setCreatorId)
      // etc.
    .build(MyComplexClass.Builder::build);
  }
}
```

My understanding here is:

- I cannot use `@ForAll` to 'inject' or provide these Arbitraries as `ForAll` is only supported in `@Property`-annotated methods
- I cannot use `@Domain` here for similar reasons
- I can't really use `ArbitrarySupplier` or similar as there is no obvious 'type' here, it's mostly just a bunch of strings

Is the best option to just create static `Arbitrary<String>` functions and call them directly?

Answer (score 1):

One initial comment: `@ForAll` also works in methods annotated with `@Provide` and in domains. Here's a simple example:

```java
class MyDomain extends DomainContextBase {

    @Provide
    public Arbitrary<String> strings(@ForAll("lengths") int length) {
        return Arbitraries.strings().alpha().ofLength(length);
    }

    @Provide
    public Arbitrary<Integer> lengths() {
        return Arbitraries.integers().between(3, 10);
    }

    // Will not be used by strings() method
    @Provide
    public Arbitrary<Integer> negatives() {
        return Arbitraries.integers().between(-100, -10);
    }

}

class MyProperties {
    @Property(tries = 101)
    @Domain(MyDomain.class)
    public void printOutAlphaStringsWithLength3to10(@ForAll String stringsFromDomain) {
        System.out.println(stringsFromDomain);
    }
}
```

Maybe the confusing thing is that the string reference in `@ForAll("myString")` is only evaluated locally (the class itself, superclasses and containing classes).
This is by purpose, in order to prevent string-based reference magic;
having to fall back to strings in the first place - since method refs cannot be used in Java annotations - is already bad enough.

As for your concrete question:

> Is the best option to just create static Arbitrary functions and call them directly?

I consider that a "good enough" approach for sharing generators within a single domain or when you have several related domains that inherit from a common superclass.

When you want to share generators across unrelated domains, you'll have to either:

- Use type-based resolution: Introduce value types for things like `RecordId`, `UUIDString` etc. Then you can use domains (or registered `ArbitraryProvider`s to generate based on type.
- Introduce annotations to mark different variants of the same type.
  You can then check the annotation in your provider method or arbitrary provider. Here's an example:

```java
class MyNumbers extends DomainContextBase {
    @Provide
    Arbitrary<Integer> numbers() {
        return Arbitraries.integers().between(0, 255);
    }
}

@Domain(MyNumbers.class)
class MyDomain extends DomainContextBase {

    @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Name {}

    @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface HexNumber {}

    @Provide
    public Arbitrary<String> names(TypeUsage targetType) {
        if (targetType.isAnnotated(Name.class)) {
            return Arbitraries.strings().alpha().ofLength(5);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Provide
    public Arbitrary<String> numbers(TypeUsage targetType) {
        if (targetType.isAnnotated(HexNumber.class)) {
            return Arbitraries.defaultFor(Integer.class).map(Integer::toHexString);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Property(tries = 101)
@Domain(MyDomain.class)
public void generateNamesAndHexNumbers(
        @ForAll @MyDomain.Name String aName,
        @ForAll @MyDomain.HexNumber String aHexNumber
) {
    System.out.println(aName);
    System.out.println(aHexNumber);
}
```

This examples also shows how one domain (`MyNumbers`) can be used
in another domain (`MyDomain`) through annotating the domain implementation class and either having a parameter being injected or use
`Arbitraries.defaultFor(TypeProvidedInOtherDomain.class)`.

But maybe there's a useful feature for sharing arbitraries missing in jqwik.
The jqwik team's happy about any suggestion.

Comment: In the example of using custom annotations above, once again the example case is for a `@Property`-annotated method. The point of confusion for me is how to utilize this for a `@Provider`-annotated method; or any means of producing a re-usable `Arbitrary` from existing ones (a `@Property` method is something not re-usable). I was looking to use `@Domain` and custom annotations with `@ForAll` on `@Provider` and couldn't find a means of doing so

Comment: The first example has the ForAll in a provider method.

Comment: I understand, however it does not (and can not?) utilize `@Domain` and is limited to a method name within the same class (as you've pointed out), seemingly making it much more difficult to (and limited in ability to) combine `Arbitrary`s outside of a `@Property` method, no?

Comment: The domain class itself can import other domains through annotations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm missing something. I see one example given of using `@ForAll` with a `@Provider` method but it's (by your admission) limited in scope to a method name within the same class (as opposed to from some `Domain` or other context).
The second example shows how to use custom annotations to disambiguate `Arbitrary` definitions of the same time, and from other domains, but limits this to use in a `@Property`. 
The crux of my question is how to combine these for a `@Provider`. It feels awkward to not be able to define on `@Provider` in terms of other Arbitraries

Comment: I changed the second example to show what I meant.